# redirecting url path to port

Tags: python, node.js, network-programming, go

I have many web apps running on a server.  Some of them I have made, some of them are open source (such as open-cloud).  All my web apps run on a specific port.  My port 80 is still free.

I would like to make a nice welcome web page to all my apps on the port 80 to allow my co-worker to see them on the local network.

My problem is to setup the urls map.  I would like the path `http://machine-name:80/open-cloud/` to be the exact same thing then `http://machine-name:8080/` (including the static files if possible).

One other possible solution would be to use sub-domaines such as `http://open-cloud.machine-name:80/` for each application.  But I do not know how to do that inside a local network.

I am looking for a solution in Python, node.js or Go (that would be awesome!).  It is important to notice that none of my web app runs on ssl and that it will probably handle very low trafic.  It is only a local network after all!

Any help and reference would be welcome.

Cheers!

Comment: Why write such a program when you can do this with something like nginx? BTW, it’s trivial (only tens of lines of code) to write in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need some kind of proxy, like http://nginx.org for example.

Then pass the domains you want to your application ports:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app1.local;

  location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header    HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that one!  It solves my problem.  I know it a basic question but I had a hard time finding an elegant solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on writing your own solution in Go, you could setup a [`http.Redirect`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect) for each URL
like this:

```
import "net/http"

var urlMap = map[string]string {
    "open-cloud": "http://machine-name:8080/",
    "some-other": "http://machine-name:9090/",
}

func redirectHandler(target string) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.Redirect(w, r, target, 301)
    }
}

func main() {
    for key, target := range urlMap {
        http.HandleFunc("/" + key, redirectHandler(target))
    }

    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

However, I would rather rely on a tool like nginx as joewhite86 already proposed.

Comment: I agree on nginx and this is what I will use.  Nevertheless I will look at your solution too because I need to get into Go more seriously!